# is it possible to look at ms word heading type (or name) from c#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

So I have a whole bunch of list items in word (Not sure if they are actually list items in word, but different levels of numbering). Each different list item level has an associated heading type associated with it.

There is heading 1, heading 2 ... etc

Is there a way for me to loop through the word doc list items, and get the heading name/type of the current list item using interop or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If it is `MSWord 2007`, then the `Word` files are actually `ZIP archives` with the main content being an `XML` file stored as `word/document.xml`

Comment: I am using word 2007. is it possible for me look at the heading types?